# Multispotted character

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who changes their face/personality based on who they are speaking to?

As in, "He was a conman with many different faces."

Thanks

Comment: You should include more details about the word you are looking for.  For example, do you want a positive or negative word?

Comment: *Two-faced*. Even if there are more than two faces, you can divide between a true face and all the others.

Answer (score 3):

> He was a conman—a **chameleon** a with many different faces.

**chameleon** (n.)

> A person who changes their opinions or behavior according to the
> situation.
>
> *Voters have misgivings about his performance as a
> political chameleon* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/chameleon)

---

> The cry went up that Banks was a **political chameleon** who had changed
> his colors far too often; all labeled him a slipping politician as he
> sought his tenth Congressional term in 1878. [Fred Harrington;
> *Fighting Politician*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fighting_Politician/b1MrEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=politician%20chameleon&pg=PA207&printsec=frontcover)

> One of the conversations concerned a politician adept at switching his
> positions, and consequently he was generally referred to as a
> **political chameleon**. [Jack Zipes; *Fairy Tales and Fables from Weimar Days*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fairy_Tales_and_Fables_from_Weimar_Days/KphMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=politician%20chameleon&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover)

> Because each crowd was different you became a **chameleon** and acted
> differently to be able to blend into them; however, it was the “in”
> group, the “really cool” group that you wanted to be part of. [R.
> Bourke and J. Loveridge; *Radical Collegiality through Student
> Voice*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Radical_Collegiality_through_Student_Voi/zCBqDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20chameleon%20who%20appeared%20differently%20to&pg=PA138&printsec=frontcover)

> During a surveillance, you often need to be a **chameleon** and change
> your appearance at a moment's notice. [D. Ribacoff and D. Santorelli;
> *I Spy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/I_Spy/vvBYCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=spy%20was%20a%20chameleon%20change%20appearances&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thanks! That's excellent.

Comment: @GlowingRectangle I would have suggested the same word, I suggest you accept this answer.